# Lens shader / Image disortion

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, effects

Well, i have a 3d scene currently with just a quad (painting) with texture on it. Between the painting and the "camera" i have places an other quad i would like to behave like a optical lens: distorting the picture "below" it
[image: scene i want to archive]
how would one achieve it preferably with a shader and some pixelbuffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example I found a while ago which does something very similar to what you want. http://www.paulsprojects.net/opengl/refract/refract.html

You will probably have to modify the code a bit to achieve the inversion effect you want, but this will get you started on the right track.

**Edit:**
By the way, you will not need the second image (the inverted small rectangle). Just use a single background image and the shader.

Comment: "the inverted small rectangle" is just first step in shader production, intended to illustrate what i will archive first

Answer (score 2):

> Between the painting and the "camera" i have places an other quad i would like to behave like a optical lens:

This is a tricky one. First one must understand that OpenGL is a so called *localized rendering model rasterizer*, which means in layman terms, that it works like pencils and brushes on a canvas.

It thus works in very contrast to global scene representation renderers like raytracers. A raytracer actually operates on a fully defined scene, because of that it can to things like refraction trivially.

Indeed one must treat OpenGL like an artist treats its tools. So any optical "effect" you want to create must be implemented by mastering various drawing techiques possible with the tools OpenGL offers. To create the effect you desire you must implement a multistage process.

For refraction you first render the scene as "seen" by the refracting object in all directions (you create a dynamic cube map), then you use this cube map as input data for rasterizing the "refracting" object, where a shader is used to determine the refracted direction of a ray of light hitting the rasterized fragments.

BTW: What holds for refraction holds for any other like interacting effect. Shadows are as non-trivial like refractions in OpenGL.